# How to get a max(date) from a list of values using Structured query in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic

I have requirement to find max(date) from a list of dates using structured query.
Below is the sample data

```
<Dates>
<Date>20200808</Date>
<Date>20200809</Date>
<Date>20200810</Date>
</Dates>
```

From the above sample data, i need to pick the result of 20200810

Comment: Structured queries are used to find documents in MarkLogic. Your example shows just a single document so please provide more details about the logic you are trying to implement and what server-side language you are using (JavaScript or XQuery).

Comment: i am using xquery and it is a lookup from different excel sheet

Answer (score 1):

If the task is to get the maximum value from a single document, something like the following should work:

```
fn:max($doc/Dates/Date/xdmp:parse-yymmdd("yyyyMMdd", fn:string(.))
```

See
https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:parse-yymmdd and
https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:max

If the task is to get the maximum value from a set of documents, one approach is to create a TDE index that projects `xs:date` values from the documents into an index and write an Optic query that uses `op:max()` to get the maximum value from the index.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Not sure that it adds much value to parse as dates in this case. I would just get the max of the numeric value and avoid the overhead.

Comment: If the element had a range index, then could also look to use cts:max https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:max